# Set property in Bunit without parameter

Tags: c#, blazor, xunit, bunit

I have an abstract base class I am trying to test that has `parameters` and a property that is used for `@ref`. I can't find a way to pass in my property to my Bunit renderer.

I use this property for storing information that I access throughout the base class.

```
public abstract class ColumnBase<TRowData> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public string? Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<FunctionalColumn<TRowData>.CellInfo>? CellTemplate { get; set; }

    public FunctionalColumn<TRowData> ColumnReference { get; protected set; } = default!;
}
```

This class would normally be used like so.. in

`StyledColumn.cs`

```
@typeparam TRowData
@inherits ColumnBase<TRowData>

<FunctionalColumn
    @ref=ColumnReference
    Title=@Title
    CellTemplate=CellTemplate
    class="some styling" />
```

I am trying to test some of the functionality that uses the `ColumnReference` so it can't be null..

First, I tried this.

`ColumnBaseTests.cs`

```
public class ColumnBaseTests : TestContext
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestRenderFragment()
    {
        var cb = new ColumnBase<TestData>() { FunctionalColumn = new FunctionalColumn() };

        // then how to test render fragment?
        // wanted something like cb.CellTemplate.MarkupMatches("my markup")
    }
}
```

Then I tried doing it in the actual markup way you do in Bunit.. (note, this `column` has a cascaded `grid` so it is a child). However this did not work either because there is no `[Parameter]` attribute for the column.

```
[Fact]
public void CellTemplateIsSet()
{
    var grid = RenderComponent<Grid<TestData>>(parameterBuilder => parameterBuilder
        .AddChildContent<ColumnBase<TestData>>(parameters => parameters
            .Add(p => p.FunctionalColumn , new FunctionalColumn <TestData>())
            //.Add(p => p.Title, "..")
        )
    );
}
```

Finally, I tried just passing in an instance of it. (note, I had to make a constructor with the `FunctionalColumn` just to see if it would work, but instead, the `AddChildContent` used the correct constructor (the one with the column) first, then used the blank constructor one, overwriting it). So then I got a null exception when accessing the `FunctionalColumn`.

```
[Fact]
public void CellTemplateIsSet()
{
    var grid = RenderComponent<Grid<TestData>>(parameterBuilder => parameterBuilder
        .AddChildContent<ColumnBase<TestData>>(p => new ColumnBase<TestData>(new FunctionalColumn()) { Title = ".."}
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: `@ref` is not a parameter. It's a way to tell the Blazor compiler that you want a reference to the instance of the component you use it on. With bUnit, you get the instance through the `Instance` property on an `IRenderedComponent`, the type that is returned to you when you call `RenderComponent`. More here: https://bunit.dev/docs/verification/verify-component-state.html

Comment: @EgilHansen sure thing and I get its not a parameter. But how can I set the reference on bUnit? Through the `ComponentParameterCollectionBuilder` presumably, but I don't see any way to set the `@ref` or even instance on it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up going with was to just test the `RenderFragement`

```
var cellTemplateRenderFragment = Render(s => s.AddContent(1, new ColumnBase<TestData>(new FunctionalColumn()).CellTemplate, 
    new FunctionalColumn<TestData>.CellInfo {
        // some variable info to pass into the render fragement
    }));
cellTemplateRenderFragment .MarkupMatches("my markup");
```

Alternatively you could create a testable class that set the underlying property.

```
private class TestableColumnBase<T> : ColumnBase<T>
{
    [Parameter] public FunctionalColumn<T> FunctionalColumnParam {
        get { return base.FunctionalColumn; }
        set { base.FunctionalColumn = value; }
    }
    
}
```

And then can be used like

```
[Fact]
public void CellTemplateIsSet()
{
    var grid = RenderComponent<Grid<TestData>>(parameterBuilder => parameterBuilder
        .AddChildContent<TestableColumnBase<TestData>>(parameters => parameters
            .Add(p => p.FunctionalColumnParam , new FunctionalColumn<TestData>())
            //.Add(p => p.Title, "..")
        )
    );
}
```